# Canvas in ImageView

Tags: c#, android, canvas, xamarin

I created `ScrollView` and `TableLayout` dynamically.

How can I add my graphics (`Canvas`) in `ImageView`?

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
...
canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);


ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(2000, 2000, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, paint);
button.Text = bitmap.Width + ";" + bitmap.Height;
imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
tableLayout.AddView(imageView);
```

Comment: extend ImageView and override its onDraw() method

Comment: OK. I changed "FilledPolygon : View" on "OvverrideImageView : ImageView"

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/drawing/fill_a_polygon/

and this code doesn't work too:
OverrideImageView view = new OverrideImageView(this);
tableLayout.AddView(view);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want whatever a canvas draws to appear in an ImageView, you need to create the canvas with a bitmap, then perform your drawing logic.

Here's an example based on your code:

```
// 2000x2000 is VERY large for an Android bitmap - consider using a smaller size?
// You may see out of memory errors with this size.
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(2000, 2000, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I create forex chart point-by-point. Forex chart is very long (10000x500, 20000x1000, etc.). I must update this ImageView every second.

Comment: Then perhaps consider not using bitmaps at all, and instead, create a custom view, and perform all drawing logic by overriding its onDraw method?

Comment: Also, if this solves ur problem, don't forget to upvote / accept so other people can use this answer